# How to generate swift class or object from XML or Json when build project in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a json file with the format like this:

```
    {
    "id":"nav_grap",
    "startDestination":0,

    "navigators":[

        {
            "id":0,
            "groupsId":"0",
            "controller_name":"LoginScreen",
            "titleVi":"login_screen",
            "titleEn":"Dang nhap",
            "actions":[{
            "name":"idaction_loginScreen_to_homeScreen",
            "destination":1

            }]},
       {
            "id":1,
            "groupsId":"1",
            "controller_name":"HomeScreen",
            "titleVi":"Cong viec",
            "titleEn":"Jobs",
            "actions":[]
       },
       {
            "id":2,
            "groupsId":"2",
            "controller_name":"NewsScreen",
            "titleVi":"Tin tuc",
            "titleEn":"News",
            "actions":[]
       },
       {
            "id":3,
            "groupsId":"3",
            "controller_name":"BiometricsScreen",
            "titleVi":"Sin trac hoc",
            "titleEn":"News",
            "actions":[]
       },
       {
            "id":4,
            "groupsId":"4",
            "controller_name":"ContactScreen",
            "titleVi":"Tin tuc",
            "titleEn":"News",
            "actions":[]
       }]
}.
```

I want to generate a class or object base on the format of this json file when I build my project so after project built I would have a object with properties like this:

```
    class ScreenConfig : Decodable{

       var id : String
       var startDestination : Int
       var navigators : [Navigator] = []

       init(id : String, startDestination : Int, navigator : [Navigator]) {
          self.id = id
          self.startDestination = startDestination
          self.navigators = navigator
         }

       init() {
                self.id = ""
                self.startDestination = 0
                self.navigators = []
              }
      }.
```

So,could anyone please tell me how can I archive this? thanks.

Comment: There is something called [GYB](https://nshipster.com/swift-gyb/) that can be used to generate swift code but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: Thanks, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: use http://www.jsoncafe.com/

Comment: @ChandanJee: that is not even close

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are finding [quicktype-xcode](https://github.com/quicktype/quicktype-xcode)

> quicktype-xcode: Creating models base on API JSON responses

To do it manually, you can use [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) or [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen), which can automate daily development processes

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a Xcode plugin for generating JSON to Swift code.

So you should build extensions to the source editor in Xcode using XcodeKit.

Source editor extensions can read and modify the contents of a source file, as well as read and modify the current text selection within the editor.

---

```
struct ScreenConfig: Decodable{

   let id : String
   let startDestination : Int
   let navigators : [Navigator]

}

struct Navigator: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let groupsId: String
    let controller_name : String


    let titleVi: String
    let titleEn: String
    let actions: [Action]?

}



struct Action: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let destination: Int

}
```

**Test Case:**

you have a json file named "one.json" in your project bundle, which is configured with your data above

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let src = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "one", withExtension: "json"){
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: src)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let model = try decoder.decode(ScreenConfig.self, from: data)
                print(model.navigators.first?.controller_name ?? "ha ha")

            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean the object will be created when the app already running on device,I mean that when I press run button on Xcode or command + B the object should be created base on the json file

Comment: Then put the test case logic in the `Target - Action`

Comment: The code has been showed, and apple's doc is clear, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, let me re-phrase my earlier comment. You have not understood what OP is asking so your answer is not relevant. OP wants to _generate_ swift code from json which clearly your answer doesn't do.

Comment: @dengApro : sorry, can you explain me what Target - Action means ?

Comment: Thanks, what your mean is interesting @Joakim Danielson

Comment: sorry too. I did not understand it well @user2905416

Answer (score 0):

Using the http://www.jsoncafe.com

```
struct TestingTest : Codable {

        let id : String?
        let navigators : [TestingNavigator]?
        let startDestination : Int?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case id = "id"
                case navigators = "navigators"
                case startDestination = "startDestination"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
                navigators = try values.decodeIfPresent([TestingNavigator].self, forKey: .navigators)
                startDestination = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .startDestination)
        }
}


struct TestingNavigator : Codable {

        let actions : [AnyObject]?
        let controllerName : String?
        let groupsId : String?
        let id : Int?
        let titleEn : String?
        let titleVi : String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case actions = "actions"
                case controllerName = "controller_name"
                case groupsId = "groupsId"
                case id = "id"
                case titleEn = "titleEn"
                case titleVi = "titleVi"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                actions = try values.decodeIfPresent([AnyObject].self, forKey: .actions)
                controllerName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .controllerName)
                groupsId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .groupsId)
                id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
                titleEn = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .titleEn)
                titleVi = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .titleVi)
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read the comments to the other answer, this is not what OP is asking for. Besides that it is unclear why you are making all properties optional and why custom `init(from:)` are needed here. Is this just copy/paste?